# How to use a plugin parameter?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, I want to use a plugin parameter.  For example, the [`profile_tasks` plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.html) supports a parameter to "Adjust the sorting output of summary tasks".

I enable this plugin by whitelisting it in the `ansible.cfg` file by:

```
[defaults]
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
```

But how do I use the parameter supported by the plugin?

Note: I just want to use it but I don't know how to. The document says "parameter" and normally I think the way to use a parameter is to "pass a parameter to a function/command line" so that's why I asked "how to pass a parameter". What I want to know is "How to use a plugin parameter".

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested it, but as the doc says, you can configure the plugin via two ways : ini entries or env.

Add below your snippet the following and it should work :

```
[defaults]
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks

[callback_profile_tasks]
sort_order = descending
```